# React: Calling JS function after bridge has been destroyed --- How to find which function

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm working on an update for our app. I've added a HeadlessTask and I've started seeing this warning in the console:

`React: Calling JS function after bridge has been destroyed`

How can I get the name of the function being executed?

Comment: I noticed i get this error as well when I don't restart the application using "react-native run-android". My guess is that when you restart the application pressing the "r" button, the bridge to react that is receiving the emitting data is not recreated, so you get this error.

Answer (score 4):

From the error message I assume you're in java (react-native Android):

When you reload on react-native, what happens behind the scenes is that the react context is getting destroyed, and a new one is being created.

That error get's thrown whenever a react-native Native Module is trying to do work, by using the old react context (the one that was valid before the reload).

The last time I saw that error it also included an explanation as to which module tried to do work by using the old context. Typically it's the `RCTDeviceEventEmitter` module trying to send a message to javascript.

You'll have to open logcat on Android studio and read the full error message.

p.s: If you're using `react-native-navigation` in your project, (after you discover which module is the trouble maker by using the logcat), make sure to search on their issues as they are heavily using the native side of react-native android, and I've seen lot's of similar issues so far.

Comment: Is there a way to use RCTDeviceEventEmitter after reloading?

Comment: What do you mean Leo? Are you unable to use `RCTDeviceEventEmitter` after reloading?

Comment: Maybe I should ask how to avoid such warning. It seems many warnings around.

Comment: @SudoPlz, I am getting something like that when using Appcenter and I only get it on the android side.

Answer (score 3):

Never found a good solution to this until recently, so thought I'd put this here in case it helps someone else. I finally got around this error by doing the following:

```java
public class RNMyNativeModule extends ReactContextBaseModule {
   private ReactApplicationContext currentContext;

   public RNMyNativeModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
      super(reactContext);
      currentContext = reactContext;
   } 

   public void myEmitFn(String emitMe) {
     currentContext
      .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
      .emit("RNMyNativeModuleEvent", emitMe);
   }    
}
```

Basically, in your module constructor, make sure you capture the currentContext in it's own variable, and just use that whenever you need it. Otherwise it gets overwritten and destroyed whenever a live reload happens, and `getReactApplicationContext()` is not actually giving you the current context.

Comment: This helped me too, however I had a similar setup already - my issue was the use of the `final` modifier of the class variable, removing it resolved the problem.